# Get distinct count - column having array of array json value

Tags: arrays, postgresql, arrayofarrays

I have one table having json column named record
we have values like

```
[ "billinfo": [
    {
      "sortKey": "z",
      "voucherList": [
        "021121",
        "021122",
        "021123"
      ]
    }
  ],
]


and 

[ "billinfo": [
    {
      "sortKey": "z",
      "voucherList": [
        "004077"
      ]
    },
    {
      "sortKey": "z",
      "voucherList": [
        "004076"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Find Distinct Count on voucherList
Ex, if there are six unique vouchers, return “6”

Comment: Postgres version, what have you tried, fiddle to work with?

Comment: When you write above, the answer is not 5? - 021121, 021122, 021123, 004077, 004076

Comment: @RaminFaracov yes, the answer will be 5